# Undefined types in vala

Tags: vala

In Vala, is it possible to declare a function like this

```
void do_something(object foo) { }
```

where `object` stands for any possible type, so that I can for example pass both an integer and a string to this function?

```
do_something("Foo Bar");
do_something(1234);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generic if you wanted:

```
void do_something<T>(T foo) {}
```

But what are you going to do with a value you can't use?

If you want to store it for later reconstitution, you can use a [GLib.Value](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gobject-2.0/GLib.Value) which will be automatically packed by the compiler:

```
void do_something(Value foo) {}
```